# Fetch Products from a category and all its sub-categories

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Am building an E-commerce site but have run into some kind of issues

**Problem**
I have a category called drinks now under this category i have two sub categories which are whiskey and non-alcoholic. Under non Alcoholic we have juice and wine drinks in the parent category for whiskey and non-alcoholic while non-alcoholic is the parent category for juice and wine. the problem is when a user clicks on drinks i want them to be able to see all the items that are both in whiskey category and the children of non-alcholic category but my query to fetch the products in this categories and bring them together is not working.

**Code**

```
public function select_from_product_page_all($cat,$level){
$que = $this->query("SELECT a.product_category_id,a.quantity, a.product_id, a.description, a.product_name, a.image, a.price, Deriv1.Count FROM `product` a  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT parent, COUNT(*) AS Count FROM `product_category` GROUP BY parent) Deriv1 ON a.product_category_id = Deriv1.parent WHERE a.parent=" . $cat);
return $que;
}
```

**Database Structure**

Products Table Columns are

product_name,quantity,price,image,description,product_category_id

Product Category Table Columns are

product_category_id,name,parent

what ties the product to a category is product_category_id, what ties a product_category to a parent category is the parent column and what is saved in the parent column is the product_category_id of the parent.

Comment: you should explain your database structure

Comment: have edited to explain database @MohammadJulfikar

Comment: so you want to show the category and all the other products related to this category,isn't it?

Comment: yes, want to show all the products in a parent category and its sub categories@MohammadJulfikar